# Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll - What could be the reason for this error?

Tags: php, windows, dll, msvcr120.dll

I get the following error generated in the windows error log, when my `php` application tries to call a `dll`. What could be the reason for this error?

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.17.0, time stamp: 0x561cc534
Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f7ce6
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000a46a9
Faulting process id: 0x178c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1491057d1d32c
Faulting application path: C:\MAS\Apache2\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
Report Id: 95c8e53e-b503-11e5-828c-aab693e55dd1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I have installed `redistributable 2012 and 2013 package` but it is still the same. I am running on `64bit` architecture.

Comment: have you installed [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: @bansi Yes. I already installed the `x86` package.

Comment: is your Apache server also x86?

Comment: @bansi Yes. `Apache Version Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15`

Comment: @SuhailGupta did you ever solve this? If so, what did you do?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck No. I had to leave this finally.